# What's ITT(In This Thread)?

Tags: usage

I 've seen some people upload their posts in a forum with ITT within the title or something. But I don't get it why that's necessary. If people reply comments at *that* thread, isn't that automatically *in that thread*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear that they are only considering **that** particular thread, whereas if you don’t state ITT people will try and muddy the waters with “but this thread says...”.